# How to Prevent ReSharper from Wrapping One-Line Statements?

Tags: resharper, resharper-8.0

What is the best way to prevent ReSharper from wrapping certain lines of code.  For example, an `if` statement with one condition and a simple body should not be wrapped.  ReSharper currently forces this line...

```
if (item == null) { return null;  }
```

... to break like this:

```
if (item == null) 
{ 
    return null;  
}
```

I don't want to blindly disable this feature necessarily... just make it a bit more intelligent.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Update for newer versions of ReSharper

(my version is 2021.1)

Since a picture is worth than a thousand words, you probably want to configure it like so. In this way it takes care of constructs such as `using` too:

[image]

Check the ones that start with `Keep existing arrangement [...]` if you want to instruct ReSharper to leave, say, single-line `if`s alone if they are already written that way.

Took me longer to figure out than I wanted it to, hopefully it will help someone else.

---

You can change this in the R# Settings:

1. Open the menu *Resharper -> Options*
2. Go to *Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Line Breaks and Wrapping*
3. Change to option *Break line in single embedded statement* to **Put on a single line** or **Do not change**

**Edit:**
As mentioned by @Alexander it would be more suitable to use the option *Break Line in a block with a single statement* which I think is available since R# 8

Comment: "Break Line in a block with a single statement" setting is more suited for mentioned code snippet, I guess.

Comment: @Alexander you're right. Seems like this option is new in R# 8.

Comment: Cannot find such option in Reshaper 2019.1

Answer (score 0):

In latest Resharper it is under General >> "Wrap log lines"

[image]